# Qual a diferença de arquitetura e engenharia de software?

Tags: arquitetura-de-software, engenharia-de-software

- Arquitetura de *software*
- Engenharia de *software*

Aparentemente esses dois conceitos são relacionados, mas qual a diferença entre eles?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Você já ouviu dizer que Arquitetura de *software* é um conceito usado pela Engenharia de *software*?

Pois bem, basicamente é isso, a Arquitetura de software nada mais é do que um conceito usado pela Engenharia de *software* para englobar as definições dos componentes de *software*, suas propriedades externas, e seus relacionamentos com outros *softwares*.

## O que é arquitetura de *software*?

> A arquitetura de *software* de um sistema consiste na definição dos componentes de *software*, suas propriedades externas, e seus relacionamentos com outros *softwares*. O termo também se refere à documentação da arquitetura de *software* do sistema. A documentação da arquitetura do *software* facilita: a comunicação entre os *stakeholders*, registra as decisões iniciais acerca do projeto de alto nível, e permite o reuso do projeto dos componentes e padrões entre projetos.

### De onde vem o conceito?

> O cargo de “Arquiteto de *Software*” como empregado hoje na indústria do *software* é mais uma herança ruim da comparação entre desenvolvimento de *software* e construção civil. Nesta última, o arquiteto faz o projeto mas, em geral, não suja as mãos no cimento.

Um fato interessante é que apenas empresas grandes, com orçamentos folgados (que, em geral, desperdiçam tempo e dinheiro com futilidades e becos sem saída) costumam oferecer o cargo de arquiteto de *software*. Eles geralmente ficam em equipes de arquitetura, longe das equipes que “sujam” as mãos no código no dia-a-dia. Ora, isso, por si só, criam as "Torres de Marfim" e uma certa animosidade latente entre as diferentes equipes – que deveriam trabalhar em conjunto todos os dias.

Não faz sentido (e não é eficiente) ter equipes de arquitetura separadas, sem contato direto e constante com as equipes de desenvolvimento. Também não faz sentido empregar arquitetos de *software* que só planejam e não participam da execução diariamente.

Usando a já batida metáfora do desenvolvimento de *software* como jardinagem é fácil perceber que estamos longe do processo utilizado, por exemplo, na construção civil ou na indústria automobilística. Não é possível projetar todo o *software* com antecedência, como um prédio ou um carro, comprar a matéria-prima, contratar os operários e implementá-lo praticamente sem desvios. O projeto é o *software* e o *software* é o projeto.

## O que é engenharia de *software*?

> Engenharia de *software* é uma área da computação voltada à especificação, desenvolvimento e manutenção de sistemas de *software*, com aplicação de tecnologias e práticas de gerência de projetos e outras disciplinas, visando organização, produtividade e qualidade

Friedrich Ludwig Bauer foi o primeiro dizendo:

> "Engenharia de *Software* é a criação e a utilização de sólidos princípios de engenharia a fim de obter software de maneira econômica, que seja confiável e que trabalhe em máquinas reais".

O próprio significado de engenharia já traz os conceitos de criação, construção, análise, desenvolvimento e manutenção.

O termo foi criado na década de 1960 e passou a ser utilizado oficialmente em 1968 na *NATO Science Committee*. Sua criação surgiu numa tentativa de contornar a crise do *software* e dar um tratamento de engenharia (mais sistemático e controlado) ao desenvolvimento de sistemas de *software* complexos. Um sistema de *software* complexo se caracteriza por um conjunto de componentes abstratos de *software* (estruturas de dados e algoritmos) encapsulados na forma de procedimentos, funções, módulos, objetos ou agentes e interconectados entre si, compondo a arquitetura do *software*, que deverão ser executados em sistemas computacionais.

Fontes:
[Wikipédia](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Engenharia_de_software), [Wikipédia 2](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arquitetura_de_software), [Keep Learning](http://blog.lucashungaro.com/2009/11/04/desenvolvedor-arquiteto-programador-engenheiro/), [Fórum Outer Space](http://forum.outerspace.terra.com.br/index.php?threads/arquitetura-de-software-x-engenheiro-de-software.262562/)

Comment: +1 excelente resposta

Comment: @JorgeB. Obrigado :D

Comment: Quando eu era mais novo, sempre quis ser um *Arquiteto de Software*. Mas depois que ganhei conhecimento vi que esse título era mais uma frescura do que algo real. Basta ser um *Engenheiro de Software*, o resto se mostra com o trabalho.

Comment: Amei muito detalhado

Answer (score 15):

## Arquitetura de *Software*

Quando se diz sobre a **Arquitetura de *Software***, se diz sobre quais tecnologias e a modelagem do *software*.

O papel do arquiteto em uma equipe desenvolvimento (que sim, existem arquitetos que também **sujam** as mãos) é ajudar a evitar o débito técnico, quedas de performance, falta de escalabilidade, que pode ser causado pelos desenvolvedores.

Arquitetos de *Software* são profissionais que tem um bom conhecimento de soluções em alto nível. Conhecem *design patterns*, conceitos como SOLID, DRY, YAGNI e tentam aplicá-los onde for cabível e possível.

Arquitetos modelam o sistema todo dia pois, como disse o colega @RodrigoBorth:

> O projeto é o *software* e o *software* é o projeto.

Projetos mudam todos os dias, seja por novas tecnologias, impossibilidade de executar o previsto, mudança de especificações, etc.

## Engenharia de *Software*

Um **Engenheiro de *Software*** é um líder de equipes de desenvolvimento. Este profissional conhece técnicas de desenvolvimento ágil, liderança de equipes.

A função de um engenheiro de *software* é manter a equipe, com seu melhor índice de produção possível, sanando problemas do **processo de desenvolvimento** de *software*.

## Portanto

Os arquitetos são aqueles que modelam e projetam o sistema e, os engenheiros são aqueles que controlam o processo até a conclusão.

Comment: -1 "Um Engenheiro de Software é um líder de equipes de desenvolvimento." Errado, idealmente todos os programadores duma empresa deveriam ser Eng. de Software. E quando eu digo eng. de software não me refiro a nenhuma Licenciatura, mas sim ao facto de "engenheirar" software.

Comment: Concordo @JorgeB. mas considerei como ocorre aqui onde trabalho. Os desenvolvedores seniores, com melhores conhecimentos sobre a engenharia são líderes de suas equipes de 3 a 5 pessoas. Todos programadores deveriam conhecer. Mas conhecimento é um processo evolutivo e, novos desenvolvedores ainda não conhecem o processo e vão conhecendo no decorrer do tempo. Idealmente todos deveriam ter conhecimentos sólidos de engenharia e arquitetura, mas na realidade alguns só querem cumprir seu horário e outros se especializam.

Comment: Caputo sendo um conhecedor ou não, um programador é por norma um Eng. de Software, sé é bom Eng ou mau isso já é outra historia.

Comment: Concordo contigo @JorgeB. estou lendo bastante sobre as definições e pretendo melhorar a resposta em breve. Obrigado!

Comment: Excelente resposta, amigo...

Comment: Essa definição de Engenheiro de Software é totalmente equivocada. Aliás nem explica o que é **Engenharia** de Software

Comment: @JorgeB. Descordo totalmente. Um Engenheiro de Software é um Programador mas um Programador pode não ser um Engenheiro de Software. Programador é aquele que sabe escrever código - passar um algoritmo para uma linguagem, quase como um tradutor. Um Engenheiro de Software é capaz de fazer o mesmo quem um Programador mas faz-lo dotados capacidades e conhecimentos técnicos de forma a o fazer sistematicamente e seguindo padrões e boas práticas. (Passei pelos dois lados e esta resposta baseia-se na minha experiência pessoal.)

Answer (score 2):

Exemplo da vida real.

A Empresa Foo tem um problema. O Sistema de Informação que eles utilizam, não está atendendo as necessidades da empresa. Eles precisam de um Sistema mais personalizado que se encaixe melhor em seus processos. Buscando uma solução, seu diretor entra em contato com a empresa Software Bar. As partes conversam e firmam um contrato para o desenvolvimento de um novo sistema para e Empresa Foo. Então, a software Bar inicia o processo de desenvolvimento da solução. Lá, existem vários tipos de profissionais, dentre eles:

Engenheiro de Software: Responsável por identificar as necessidades exatas do cliente, descrever os processos da empresa, identificar os envolvidos (classes) nos processos, desenhar e aprovar o projeto* junto ao arquiteto, departamento comercial e cliente.

Arquiteto de Software: Responsável por identificar as melhores tecnologias para desenvolver a solução proposta pelo engenheiro, definir e reunir os recursos necessários para o projeto, coordenar o trabalho da equipe de desenvolvimento.

Ambos tem competência para participar do processo de desenvolvimento. A diferença está na ÊNFASE.

*Existem dois projetos. O projeto da solução, que envolve o diagnóstico do problema e a coleta de informações e dados do cliente. Este projeto é elaborado com o envolvimento do cliente. Após aprovação, este primeiro projeto vai para a equipe de Arquiterura que o utilizará como guia para o desenvolvimento do SOFTWARE EM SI, iniciando esta etapa com a elaboração de um segundo projeto estritamente interno.

## ARQUITETURA E ENGENHARIA DE SOFTWARE

> Arquitetura de software é o estudo da organização global dos sistemas de software bem como do relacionamento entre seus subsistemas e componentes. Ela serve como uma estrutura que permite o entendimento de componentes de um sistema e seus inter-relacionamentos, especialmente daqueles atributos que são consistentes ao longo do tempo e de implementações. Lamentavelmente, arquiteturas de software recebem pouco ou nenhum tratamento sistemático na maioria dos cursos de Ciência da Computação, tanto no nível de graduação quanto de pós-graduação. A Engenharia de software, por sua vez, capacita o profissional a se aprofundar em todos os conceitos, métodos e processos relacionados com o desenvolvimento de aplicações, incluindo especificação, projeto, desenvolvimento, verificação, validação e gerenciamento.

Prof. Flávio Mello - UFRJ https://www.im2c.poli.ufrj.br/members/fmello/aes.html

Answer (score -6):

Entre dever conhecer e de fato conhecer é oque separar os profissionais, não é simples assim. Portanto, a indústria tem que parar de usar os nomes errados para atrair profissionais. Um engenheiro de software é uma pessoa normalmente muito experiente, anos de profissão, pois já passou por todos os cenário possíveis e pode de fato assumir uma responsabilidade tão grande. Quando vejo em vagas oferecidas com o título de Engenheiro de Software, onde pedem conhecimento técnicos como linguagem de programação, vejo o quanto estamos imaturos na área.

Comment: _Um engenheiro de software é uma pessoa normalmente muito experiente, anos de profissão, pois já passou por todos os cenário possíveis e pode de fato assumir uma responsabilidade tão grande_ . Não, Engenheiro de Software é a pessoa que concluiu o curso de Engenharia de Software. É uma carreira acadêmica formal e reconhecida. Creio que não dá muito espaço para interpretação pessoal.