# Qual a diferença entre arquitetura, engenharia, ciência, análise, design, programação e codificação?

Tags: terminologia, engenharia-de-software, arquitetura-de-software, ciência-da-computação

Eu sei, tem a pergunta [Qual a diferença de arquitetura e engenharia de software?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/25403/101).

Ali já responde em parte. Ainda que eu não tenha ficado 100% satisfeito com as respostas, que até são boas. Se puder fazer algo melhor, ajudará, caso contrário deixa o que já tem lá. **Especificamente a arquitetura define o que?**

Mas acho que o que separa cada função destas disciplinas do título não fica claro.

Por exemplo, **do que trata a ciência da computação que não trata na engenharia de software? Ou vice-versa.**

Programação e codificação parecem a mesma coisa. Mas é mesmo?

O mesmo pode ser dito de análise e *design*. Pra mim parecem coisas diferentes. Análise talvez seja um estranho nisso (#FicaaDicaPraResponder).

Eu vejo estas coisas como uma hierarquia ou fases do processo de desenvolvimento de software como um todo, por isso acho que todas estão relacionadas diretamente, por isso fiz em uma pergunta só.

Então **quero entender a linha que determina onde começa uma e outra, o que cada uma define**.

Não quero detalhes, só linhas gerais. Se for necessário detalhes de cada função farei perguntas específicas.

Note que quero saber sobre as funções efetivamente exercidas, não sobre cargos. Eu sei que uma mesma pessoa pode ter mais de uma função, e que o cargo que ela ocupa não indica nada que ela pode ou não fazer.

Já conheço a Wikipedia, pode colocar *links* para complementar, mas uma resposta boa vai além do que está lá. Inclusive não sei se é uma fonte tão confiável assim nesse assunto.

Não quero opiniões, precisa de algum fundamento, caso contrário considerarei a resposta **errada**.

Comment: Se ninguém der uma boa resposta eu responderei depois.

Comment: Sobre arquitetura no título, não ficou muito claro se você se referia a arquitetura de software ou arquitetura de solução... O texto também não deixou claro qual aspecto está sendo tratado. Talvez a ambiguidade tenha sido proposital?, para haver resposta nos dois sentidos?

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado sim, a dúvida é generalizada mesmo, vale para ambos. É tudo muito confuso até onde vai cada coisa, inclusive o que você citou, então falou de ambos. A ambiguidade foi proposital.

Comment: Preenchi as principais lacunas que eu tenho algo a acrescentar (com exceção de Análise de Algoritmo) na resposta https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/206988/64969

Comment: Só pra constar, coloquei na descrição da recompensa que ela irá para a resposta aceita pelo autor da pergunta, mas no caso de isso não ocorrer irá para a resposta com mais votos no final do período.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

## Ciência da Computação

Ciência da Computação é uma área da matemática, assim como também é o nome de um curso de faculdade.

Na faculdade de *Ciência da Computação* (as vezes referida como *Ciências da Computação*), estuda-se os básicos de programação para, então, poder entrar na ciência da computação em si. Também se estuda conceitos relativos a criação de sistemas e software, como levantamento de requisitos, ciclos de projetos etc.

Dentre as subáreas da ciência da computação (exceto engenharia), destaco as seguintes:

1. algoritmos
2. complexidade de algoritmos
3. teoria dos autômatos
4. linguagens formais
5. estrutura de dados
6. bancos de dados
7. inteligência artificial

Quem pratica a Ciência da Computação é chamado de **cientista da computação**.

## Engenharia da computação

A área *Engenharia da computação* estuda a vida da criação do software. É uma área de estudo muito ampla, que vai desde análise de sistemas existentes, comunicação entre pessoas que vão usar o sistema, comunicação de pessoas dentro da montagem do sistema, comunicação entre sistemas, técnicas de gerenciamento de projeto etc.

Uma das áreas da Engenharia de software tem uma sobreposição grande com a área de *Gerência de projetos* da *Adminstração*, mas tem peculiaridades muito específicas. Por exemplo, o manifesto Ágil surgiu para suprir demandas específicas do mercado de software, que depois esses conceitos foram aproveitados para outros esquemas de projeto.

> Opinião: pelo que eu (Jefferson Quesado) li sobre a origem do termo *Engenheiro de Software*, esse termo foi cunhado por uma espécie de gourmetização do mercado, por questões de marketing para fornecer ao cliente uma maior confiança, pois quando se diz que um **engenheiro** está trabalhando tem-se o preceito de que é alguém extremamente capaz, formado a fogo e sofrimento por cinco ou seis anos de intensos estudos na faculdade.

Um dos aspectos tratados pela engenharia de software, e que uso bastante no trabalho, é reduzir custos e aumentar produtividade relativa de cada um dos colaboradores (seja qual for a medida de produtividade: *sloc*, entrega de valor ao cliente, satisfação da gerência, vendabilidade do produto etc).

Quem pratica a Engenharia de Software é chamado de **Engenheiro de Software**.

## Arquitetura...

Arquitetura trata sobre o desenho geral, funcional e comportamental de determinado pedaço de software. Depois de fazer o desenho e determinar o que se deve/pretende alcançar, cabe aos engenheiros tornar essa arquitetura viável.

### ... de solução

Vou colocar aqui as palavras de __, escritas no parágrafo do artigo [O Papel do Arquiteto de Solução](https://www.infoq.com/br/articles/papel-arquiteto-solucao), pois elas são melhores do que eu seria capaz de escrever:

> Um arquiteto de solução atua primariamente na construção de soluções baseadas nas necessidades do negócio, fazendo uso dos serviços e recursos tecnológicos já existentes na empresa. Outro objetivo é o de alinhar novas soluções aos princípios arquiteturais já definidos, respeitando os padrões e integrações da empresa.

Onde trabalho, tivemos de bolar uma nova arquitetura para o sincronismo do app que a empresa vende. Antes de começar a codificar, foi discutido amplamente sobre como seria essa nova comunicação. Para isso, foi feito uma coalizão com 3 pessoas para bolar qual seria a solução e, se fosse possível, testar um protótipo:

- o nosso mago de banco e sql para determinar qual informação deveria chegar no dispositivo (200 tabelas com informações que devem chegar no dispositivo)
- o especialista da parte de servidor e comunicação aplicação/banco
- eu, como especialista em transmissão e *parsing* de informação e também do sincronismo legado.

Nosso problema foi detectado como *impossível de contornar* mais ou menos em 20/outubro, a solução foi desenhada em 25/outubro e o primeiro protótipo da ideia ficou pronto em 28/outubro. Em 04/novembro, pusemos a solução em campo (beta). Uma versão finalmente estável e esteticamente bonita para o usuário ficou pronta dia 19/dezembro.

No exemplo acima, o trabalho da arquitetura de solução deu-se dos dias 20 a 25 de outubro, então passou-se pela arquitetura de software e, de resto, foi escrita e construção do software (portanto, trabalho de engenharia de sotware).

Quem pratica a Arquitetura de Solução é chamado de **arquiteto de solução**.

### ... de software

A arquitetura de software se preocupa com os níveis mais altos de abstração do software. Ela se preocupa com os elementos de software, seus componentes e suas relações.

No exemplo do sincronismo, que tivemos na empresa, a arquitetura de solução definiu que os dados seriam navegados a partir do ponto de origem (identificação do usuário do dispositivo móvel), passando pelos relacionamentos até chegar em determinada tabela; caso houvesse algo de novo (linhas novas, relacionamento criado que dava acesso a linhas não alcançadas, relacionamento atualizado que dava acesso à novas linhas na tabela), essa informação seria enviada. O envio se daria na forma de um mapeamento onde cada tabela era um campo no JSON e seu valor um vetor de objetos JSON com mapeamento coluna -- valor (valores nulos na coluna eram omitidos) [em nota: sim, sabemos que tem jeitos mais eficientes de se transmitir dados e estamos trabalhando numa evolução desse sincronismo]. Esse sistema novo de sincronismo deveria ser aplicado **imediatamente** nas tabelas com maior peso no sistema, sendo que as demais deveriam ser mantidas ainda no sistema legado. Assim, pudemos separar logicamente os componentes e trabalhar neles independentemente. A nossa arquitetura de software ficou mais ou menos assim:

- funções no MSSQL para fazer a navegação
- função no banco que transforma um `SELECT` em um objeto JSON
- servidor usando Spring Boot que captura o JSON fornecido pelo banco e o adequa para serialização (colocando os demais componentes do JSON previstos pela solução, como o nome da tabela seguido de dois-pontos, as vírgulas para separar as linhas/objetos JSON dentro do mesmo vetor)
- recebimento HTTP em TotalCross (deu origem a essa classe: [HttpConn](https://github.com/TotalCross/tc-utilities/blob/master/src/main/java/com/tc/utils/utilities/io/HttpConn.java))
- compilação SAX de JSON em TotalCross (o modelo DOM de referência [org.json](https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java) custava muita memória para o nosso caso)
- inserção no SQLite

Quem pratica a Arquitetura de Software é chamado de **arquiteto de software**.

## Análise...

### ... e desenvolvimento de sistemas

### ... de algoritmo

## Design

Existe o Design de Algoritmo, de Solução, de Interface, cada um com suas peculiaridades...

Design de Algoritmo só ouvi falar integrado com Arquitetura de Solução, normalmente como um ponto a ser melhorado. Por exemplo, um algoritmo pode ter um design de fazer resgate em `N + 1` de uma informação no banco, então sugere-se que se mude o design desse algoritmo para fazer esse resgate em uma ida ao banco.

O Design de Solução tem uma ampla interseção com Arquitetura de Solução, tão grande que eu particularmente não sei diferenciar (se é que há distinção).

O Design de Interface está intimamente relacionado com a UX (*User Experience*/experiência de usuário) que se deseja passar ao usuário do sistema. Um webdesigner trabalha o JavaScript e o CSS para fornecer uma experiência agradável ao usuário.

Quem trabalha com Design de Interface é chamado de **Designer de Interface**.

## Codificação

[Etimologia](https://pt.wiktionary.org/wiki/codifica%C3%A7%C3%A3o):reunir normas em forma de código.

A codificação é, basicamente, transformar em código.

No livro **[Shell Script Profissional](http://shellscript.com.br/)** do [Aurélio Verde](http://aurelio.net/), ele fala sobre a diferenciação entre scripteiros e programadores; sobre essa diferenciação, parafraseando do site:

> **Capítulo 1 - Programas sim, scripts não**
>   Este livro ensina a fazer programas e não scripts. Seu objetivo é transformar "scripteiros" em programadores, dando o embasamento necessário e ensinando as boas práticas da programação. Isso melhorará a qualidade do código, facilitando muito o trabalho de manutenção futura. Chega de reescrever scripts porque o código original estava incompreensível, chega de dores de cabeça pela falta de limpeza e organização. Aprenda a fazer programas em shell, do jeito certo.

A diferença entre um scripteiro e um programador é referente à qualidade do código produzido, capacidade de reutilização e custo de manutenção. No caso específico do shell script, codificar é... digamos assim... scriptar.

Então, segundo Aurélio Verde, codificar não é a mesma coisa de programar.

Quem pratica a Codificação são conhecidos informalmente como **codadores** (pelo menos a nível de maratona de programação, referíamos a nós mesmos assim =]).

## Programação

É a parte de criação de programas. Um programa é diferenciado de um emaranhado de códigos por ser mais barato de manter e de expandir.

A codificação é uma parte necessária da programação, porém ela não se dá apenas através da criação/transcrição de código. Programar exige uma maior disciplina e pensar no próximo que vai pegar no sistema que você está deixando para trás... Por experiência pessoal, posso afirmar que muitas vezes o próximo é o seu *eu* do futuro, então tente deixar um bom trabalho para ele.

Quem pratica a Programação é chamado de **programador**.

Quem pratica a Programação e é gourmetizado é chamado de **engenheiro de software**.

Comment: A ideia é atrás de mais informações e continuar a resposta, já que é uma pergunta com uma resposta muita ampla e não consigo no meu tempo livre no trabalho para responder tudo ao mesmo tempo

Comment: Procura-se quem possa preencher as lacunas dessa resposta! E quam possa melhorar os itens já existentes

Answer (score 11):

**Arquitetura**

No campo civil, é [projetar e edificar o ambiente habitado pelo ser humano](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arquitetura), buscando expectativas como conforto, aproveitamento de espaço, aproveitamento de luz, circulação de ar, etc.

No campo de software, [definição dos componentes de software, suas propriedades externas, e seus relacionamentos com outros softwares](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arquitetura_de_software). Buscando separação de responsabilidade, testabilidade, manutenibilidade, complexidade ciclomática, escalabilidade, entre outras práticas.

**Engenharia**

Realizações de cálculos científicos, onde se [aplicam os conhecimentos matemáticos e técnicos](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Engenharia) em computação. Comumente utilizados em softwares embarcados em aeronaves, dispositivos de análises sísmicas, redes neurais e inteligencia artificial, renderizações gráficas, jogos, e demais.

**Ciência**

Por sí só quer dizer [Conhecimento, Estudo](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ci%C3%AAncia). Usado no meio acadêmico para titular [a ciência que estuda as técnicas, metodologias e instrumentos computacionais](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ci%C3%AAncia_da_computa%C3%A7%C3%A3o). Por assim, estuda-se a história da computação, tem-se os primeiros contatos e estuda-se teorias e concepções de suas partes.

**Análise**

Normalmente referindo-se à Análise de Sistemas, não em a necessidade de ter relação com campo de TI, mas sim [com estudos de processos a fim de encontrar o melhor caminho racional para que a informação possa ser processada](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/An%C3%A1lise_de_sistemas). Mapeando o fluxo de um processo de como alguma atividade ocorre, passa-se a ter o controle deste processo. Então levanta-se oportunidades de melhorias, aplica-as e cria-se indicadores para acompanhamento. Quando o fluxo deste processo está satisfatório, aí sim podemos planejar sua informatização.

> "The first rule of any technology used in a business is that automation applied to an efficient operation will magnify the efficiency. The second is that automation applied to an inefficient operation will magnify the inefficiency.” Gates, Bill - The Road Ahead

**Design**

Se tivermos falando sobre *Interface de Usuário*, é podemos usar a mesma definição do arquiteto civil: É a prática de fazer o ser humano/usuário/cliente a se sentir bem dentro/utilizando seu sistema. Visualmente, didaticamente, sentindo iterações e responsividade do sistema sobre suas ações. Cuida do bem estar visual e prático do sistema para com seu utilizador.

Já falando de design de backend, pode-se entender como o design de como seus componentes - arquivos, códigos, projectos - estão visualmente organizados, com um fácil entendimento de sua estrutura de pastas e especialmente de sua nomenclaturas.

**Programação e Codificação**

Estamos falando de software, portanto esses dois, neste contexto, são sim semelhantes. Programar entende-se por "criar um programa", e codificar em "criar um código", código esse que, após terminado, irá gerar um programa - software.

Answer (score 0):

"Por exemplo, do que trata a ciência da computação que não trata na engenharia de software? Ou vice-versa.":

Simples, ciência da computação envolve muito mais áreas do que a engenharia de software. A engenharia de software é em linhas gerais,é o planejamento/desenho/arquitetura do software, é basicamente desenvolvimento de software, o título de engenheiro/arquiteto/analista-desenvolvedor, são apenas isso, títulos, pois eles fazem praticamente o mesmo trabalho. É a mesma coisa que vc perguntar qual a diferença do engenheiro/analista/cientista/adm de dados, não tem, porque fazem basicamente a mesma coisa mesma coisa.

A ciência da computação, tem muito mais áreas do que desenvolvimento:
Cc envolve banco de dados, inteligencia artificial, redes, processamento de imagens, sinais e sistemas,algoritmos avançados, métodos de desenvolvimento, etc... (aqui já um pouco para engenharia), e cada uma delas não necessariamente está ligado a outra, vc pode estudar e se especializar,ser um PhD em qualquer uma delas, o desenvolvimento de software é uma das áreas, só isso.