# Qual o profissional e a área específica que definem o layout dos dados em arquivos em um projeto de software?

Tags: banco-de-dados, arquivo, engenharia-de-software, estrutura-de-dados, independente-de-linguagem

Quem e como define o layout dos dados em softwares como Editores, SGBDs ou até mesmo quem cria as codificações de texto? Quando digo "layout dos dados", quero dizer, por exemplo, a forma como um arquivo PDF armazena os dados do documento; o que vem primeiro no arquivo, a codificação, os padrões para que os softwares consigam entender o arquivo, etc. No caso de SGBDs, quem e como projeta o layout que garante a eficiência e segurança dos bancos de dados? Qual a área que estuda isso?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Em geral é chamado de engenheiro de software, mas atende também por desenvolvedor, programador, arquiteto e um monte de outros nomes. Não existe algo tão específico assim e há poucas definições formas do que cada função deveria fazer. Eu fiz até uma [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/206855/101) e dei uma [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/207541/101) sobre isto.

Em geral a mesma pessoa que projeta todo o resto determina os *layouts* de arquivos ou outras formas. Na prática o *layout* do arquivo não deixa de ser uma estrutura de dados, uma das coisas mais importantes do desenvolvimento de software é que é comum as pessoas negligenciarem. Quando ela é bem feita fica mais fácil produzir os algoritmos em torno dela e evoluir o código e toda arquitetura.

Claro que em um projeto grande pode uma pessoa ser destacada para fazer isto, mas não é comum. Talvez lá seja um modelador de dados, mas nunca vi o termo sendo usado para isso, muito menos alguém ser só isso. É mais ou menos como dizer que o médico é especialista em fazer costura de pele.

Talvez por algumas pessoas acharem isso estudam uma parte e não o todo e aí cometem erros por não saber tudo o que precisa.

Globalmente isso não deixa de ser a engenharia de software, mais especificamente é a área de [estrutura de dados](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure).

Embora tangencialmente possa  ajudar a segurança, pouco tem a ver com a estrutura de dados em si.

[Leitura sobre estruturas de banco de dados](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_storage_structures).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Obrigado pelo esclarecimento. Mas acho que onde eu usei "segurança", eu também deveria ter colocado "confiabilidade". Não sei se isso tem a ver, mas, por exemplo, vamos supor que um arquivo tenha mais chance de se corromper no final, eu colocando a parte mais importante dos dados no começo, talvez a chance de recuperar dados em caso de perdas fosse maior. Eu quis mais nesse sentido. Mas posso estar equivocado.

Comment: * Eu quis dizer [...]

Comment: @Carlos muito comum os termos serem confundidos, eu mesmo vez ou outra intercambio eles indevidamente. Uma estrutura criada redundantemente é importante pra dar mais confiabilidade, ainda que traga outros "problemas"

Answer (score 2):

A equipe como um todo define como serão tratados os dados, em uma reunião por exemplo.

Após isto você tem toda a documentação de desenvolvimento e o escopo do software com suas fases de requisitos, etc..