# Qual a diferença entre um programador e um engenheiro de software?

Tags: terminologia, engenharia-de-software, arquitetura-de-software, ciência-da-computação

Estou ciente que o site já possui as perguntas [Qual a diferença de arquitetura e engenharia de software?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/25403/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-de-arquitetura-e-engenharia-de-software) e [Qual a diferença entre arquitetura, engenharia, ciência, análise, design, programação e codificação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/206855/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-arquitetura-engenharia-ci%C3%AAncia-an%C3%A1lise-design-progra/206988#206988). Entretanto, gostaria de saber se há alguma diferença na função exercida em uma empresa ou nos conhecimentos adquiridos por quem é programador e por quem é engenheiro de software.

Seria interessante se as respostas a esta pergunta contemplassem os itens a seguir em maior ou menor grau:

- É necessário ter feito curso superior para ser considerado engenheiro de software?
- O engenheiro de software ainda programa ou ele é o gerente de projetos executados pelos programadores?
- É possível ser engenheiro de software sem ser programador?

Comment: Da resposta que você linkou: "Quem pratica a Programação é chamado de programador.  Quem pratica a Programação e é gourmetizado é chamado de engenheiro de software."

Comment: Foi em cima da informação aqui : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_engineer?wprov=sfsi1, seção overview

Comment: Em Portugal só é considerado engenheiro quem pertencer á ordem dos engenheiros. Espero que a resposta á sua última questao seja um inequiveco nao.

Comment: Fiz o possível pra salvar a pergunta. Era o que queria? Era o que dava.

Comment: Ficou muito bom.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> É necessário ter feito curso superior para ser considerado engenheiro de software?

<strike>No Brasil não há regulamentação da profissão, que filosoficamente eu sou favorável, feita do jeito certo, então todo mundo pode fazer o que quiser.</strike>

*Oficialmente isso mudou e agora oficialmente você não pode mais ser um Engenheiro de Software sem ter o registro no CREA e atender as demandas deles. Eles conseguiram fazer o pior dos mundos e fazer a alegria das pessoas que são contra a regulamentação porque é só para dar dinheiro para um grupo de pessoas que controla essas instituições, o que acabou sendo verdade nesse caso. A regulamentação deveria ser algo sério para ajudar o setor ficar melhor de alguma forma, isso que foi feito eu totalmente sou contra.

Não há normas que determinem os nomes de cargos, funções ou outras denominações. Meio que cada um chama do que quiser. Então é possível ser qualquer coisa.

Não tem atividades claramente definidas do que cada cargo faz, inclusive porque é comum a mesma pessoas fazer várias dessas coisas. Uma coisa é função real, outra é o cargo que ela ocupa. Se ela é gerente, se programa, isso tudo não importa. Não é uma coisa burocrática que deve ser seguida. É o que faz sentido para o trabalho daquela equipe.

Por isso que perguntei no meu *post* lá sobre funções no geral, falando de atividades e não de cargos. Cargo é só nomenclatura. A não ser que regulamente e defina com precisão o que é cada cargo, o que aí eu sou contra.

Na pergunta *linkada* que eu fiz, eu espero que tenha boas respostas que falem sobre as atividades de cada uma das funções.

> É possível ser engenheiro de software sem ser programador?

O cargo e até a função muitas vezes tem a ver com experiência, com capacidade de realização de fazer determinadas tarefas, mesmo que nem sempre ocorra na prática.

> O engenheiro de software ainda programa ou ele é o gerente de projetos executados pelos programadores?

Eu "conheço" cientista de primeira linha que nunca programou, nunca usou um computador. Tem gerente de projeto que é mais voltado para o produto e não para o desenvolvimento. Tem engenheiros que programam tudo, outros só as linhas gerais. Quem é bom em uma coisa não é necessariamente bom em outra, seja algo que pareça hierarquicamente acima ou abaixo.

Daí vem o conflito que os chefes acham seus funcionários muito fracos e esses últimos acham que os chefes entendem nada. Ocorre isso, mas é menos comum do que as pessoas percebem. Quase sempre por causa do [efeito Dunning-Krugger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunning%E2%80%93Kruger_effect).

Para ser engenheiro é preciso profundo entendimento e um pensamento de engenheiro. Precisa entender o todo com muita clareza. O programador tem que se preocupar mais com os detalhes. Em geral ele deveria ser muito bom com o nível mais baixo. O que vejo é que isso raramente ocorre, o programador muitas vezes é só uma pessoa menos qualificada. Enquanto que o engenheiro real (não só um título no papel) costuma programar e bem. O engenheiro real não é só um engenheiro de projetos.

O programador deveria estar mais para um pedreiro ou mestre de obras. Mas na prática o que vemos é só alguém que faz o mesmo que o engenheiro mas ele é menos qualificado. O engenheiro é o antigo analista de sistemas.  Alguém que só reproduz receitas de bolo e preenche lacunas é programador. Pra mim o programador está com os (muitos) dias contados. Acho que ainda vamos usar o termo para a atividade mais bruta do processo de desenvolvimento de software.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 4):

> É necessário ter feito curso superior para ser considerado engenheiro de software?

Bom, para deter o título de Engenheiro, sim, é necessário. Mas o conhecimento é livre, se estudar e dominar computação e matemática suficiente, pode-se sim trabalhar na função de engenheiro de software em alguma solução.

> O engenheiro de software ainda programa ou ele é o gerente de projetos executados pelos programadores?

Engenheiro é uma posição Técnica, enquanto Gerente é uma posição de Gestão, não possuem relação. [Nessa minha resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/207066/3825) eu cito isso: o engenheiro de software é o cara que utiliza de conhecimentos matemáticos para desenvolver um programa.

Imagine um software que faça simulação de cálculos de sequencia de DNA. Não estamos falando de um sistema de *LOB - Line of Business*, mas de um programa que realiza calculos com processamento intenso, apenas resolvendo equações matemáticas. O Engenheiro de Software é o cara ideal para pegar as equações que um engenheiro biomédico - eu acho - criou e transforma em um programa, levando em conta todo conhecimento de computação e matemático afim de criar esse programa com máxima performance e a prova de erros.

O mesmo ocorre nos campos de ciências, de inteligência artifical, de games, etc.

> É possível ser engenheiro de software sem ser programador?

Se vc diz ter o título - formação superior - e não trabalhar na área? Sim é possível. Mas se o profissional se dedicou e se preparou para exercer a função com excelência, não vejo motivo para abrir mão, afinal houve paixão envolvida e etc. Mas daí vira outra conversa.